# Enable overloaded var_dump while also in xdebug.mode=debug

Tags: php, xdebug

The new Xdebug seems to disable the overloaded `var_dump()` function while in debug mode. I like to use both `var_dump()` and breakpoint debugging, but I'm forced to swap back and forth from `xdebug.mode=develop` for var_dump and `xdebug.mode=debug` for breakpoints.

Is there any way to enable the overloaded `var_dump()` while staying in `xdebug.mode=debug`?

It's not the end of the world, but a bit annoying to have to swap back and forth when I need a clean `var_dump()` for quick analyzing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just list **both** modes via comma:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
```

From https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

> You can enable multiple modes at the same time by comma separating their identifiers as value to **xdebug.mode**: `xdebug.mode=develop,trace`.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Thank you. I thought being forced into one or the other made zero sense.

Comment: @JustinCarlson did it overload the var_dump ? as I know active both mods will not increase the overloaded?

Answer (score -1):

you can determine the depth level you want to dump from

```
;try put it 10 or 13 and see the result
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
```

check this

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_depth

I hope it's helpful